# how to remove firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened listener?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, react-native-firebase

I am working on a react native project and using react-native-firebase library. Setting up listener is working but I am not able to find a way to remove listener.

I am setting up this listener on homepage so whenever user reach to homepage. Listener get registered multiple times and action multiple times as result.

I want to destroy this listener then again start a new one.

```
firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen) => {
        if (notificationOpen) {
          const notification: Notification = notificationOpen.notification;
          if(notification.data.type){
          }
        }
      });
```

If anyone can help, that will be appreciated...

Answer (score 4):

You need to call the listener **again** in order to remove it as mentioned in the [**docs**](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.3.x/notifications/receiving-notifications#4)-Listen-for-a-Notification-being-opened).

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.notificationOpenedListener = firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen) => {
          //... Your Stuff
   }
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    this.notificationOpenedListener();
}
```

Comment: I don't want it to remove on unmount but I want to remove it on logout. When user will logout it will destroy... Do we have any way?

Comment: this.notificationOpenedListener = `firebase.notifications().onNotificationOpened((notificationOpen) => {
    if (notificationOpen) {
        const notification: Notification = notificationOpen.notification;
        if(notification.data.type){
            firebase.notifications().removeAllDeliveredNotifications()
        }
    }
});
console.log('notificationOpenedListener', this.notificationOpenedListener());`
this.notificationOpenedListener() ->> this is undefined

Comment: This is because console executes faster before the function is initialized

Comment: I tried the same, but it's not working. Its registered multiple time due to this all other actions also called multiple times.